# reference for periodic distributions $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb T).$

Tags: reference-request, distribution-theory

I am looking for some introduction to theory of periodic distributions $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb T).$

> Would you please suggest some reference book?

[ I am familiar with [distibutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) on $\mathbb R$. For instance, Rudin's Functional Analysis Chapter 6]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "Pseudo Differential Operators and Symmetries" of M. Ruzhansky and V. Turunen chapter 3-4.